# Expected value of the random variable $Xe^X$ where $X\sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, expected-value

It is known that 
$$
E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^x\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-0.5x^2}\; dx= e^{0.5}
$$
while 
$$
E(Xe^X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^x\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-0.5x^2}\; dx
$$
By integration by parts, I get $\displaystyle\left.xe^{0.5}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - xe^{0.5}$, but I am stuck here. I suppose I cannot say the first part is $0$ as it is divergent?

Comment: I do not think that you may use the first result for the  integration by parts of the second integral.

Comment: Since the mgf of $X$ is $M(t)=E(e^{tX})=e^{t^2/2}$, we have $M'(t)|_{t=1}=E(Xe^X)=\sqrt e$.

Comment: Your formulas are missing some square root signs.

Answer (score 2):

Applying $\partial_t$ to $\Bbb Ee^{tX}=e^{t^2/2}$, $\Bbb EXe^{tX}=te^{t^2/2}$, so $\Bbb EXe^X=e^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the density of $X\sim N(0,1)$ by $\phi$, i.e., $$\phi(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}\,\qquad ,\, t\in\mathbb R$$

Then your first line should have read $$E\left[e^X\right]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x \phi(x)\,dx=\sqrt e$$

To evaluate $E\left[Xe^X\right]$, keep in mind that $$\phi'(t)=-t\phi(t)$$

and integrate by parts taking $u=e^t$ as first function and $dv=t\phi(t)$, i.e. $v=-\phi(t)$.

We arrive at

\begin{align}
E\left[Xe^X\right]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty te^t\phi(t)\,dt
\\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u\,dv
\\\\&=uv \Big|_{-\infty}^\infty -\int_{-\infty}^\infty v\,du
\\\\&=-\underbrace{\lim_{\substack{a\to-\infty \\ b\to +\infty}} e^t \phi(t)\Big|_{a}^{b}}_{0}+\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^t\phi(t)\,dt}_{E(e^X)}
\\\\&=\sqrt e
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But could you kindly explain how do you arrive at the 4th line? (E($Xe^X$))

Comment: @waipun Which part is unclear?

Comment: @StubbornAtom you take the function $e^{t}$ out of the integral in line two at the beginning. How does this work?

Comment: @Karl As far as I remember, this is integration by parts, taking $e^t$ as the first function and $t\phi(t)$ as the second function.

Comment: @StubbornAtom but here $e^t$ is not defined then! It has a meaning inside the integral, but outside? What is $t$ here?

Comment: @Karl I do not follow. Tell me what I should have written.

Comment: @StubbornAtom you have to know what you want to write, but $e^t$ at the beginning of the second line is just meaningless!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nobody, I will try with $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-0.5x^2}$:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^x((-x)\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-0.5x^2})dx  = [e^x \phi(x)]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^x \phi(x) dx = 0
-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^x \phi(x) dx = -e^{1/2}$

Similar to @StubbornAtoms solution, but the terms have all a meaning.